# How to decode variable object in variable array with jsonDecoder in swift

Tags: json, swift, decodable

I am new in SWIFT. I have been fighting with swift for a long time to decode my custom JSON.
But I couldn't.

This is my JSON :
tablesArray is an array and it has more than one tables as jsonobject
But These objects are variable but keys of objects are fixed. For instance; settingsTable can't be in tablesArray at next request, or notificationsTable can be added as extra.

```
{
    "result": true,
    "message": "allowed",
    "messageType": "nothing",
    "action": "get",
    "tablesArray": [
        {
            "settingsTable": [
                {
                    "id": "1",
                    "available": "true",
                    "forceToUpdate": "true",
                    "currentVersion": "1.5",
                    "versionMessage": "Process is completed"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "userTable": [
                {
                    "userId": "4",
                    "userDate": "2023-12-03 20:00:22",
                    "userNameSurname": "David ELI",
                    "userGender": "Male",
                    "userMailAddress": "david@eli.com",
                    "userPhoneNumber": "00495770000000",
                    "userStatus": "active"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "memberTable": [
                {
                    "memberId": "123",
                    "memberDate": "2023-04-17 17:20:17",
                    "memberStatus": "active",
                    "memberStatusDescription": "Created by system",
                }
                        ]
        },
        {
            "personnelTable": [
                {
                    "personnelId": "31",
                    "personnelDate": "2023-04-17 17:20:17",
                    "personnelLevel": "Engineer",
                    "personnelStatus": "active",
                    "personnelStatusDescription": "Created by system",
                    "companyId": "1"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

```
try JSONDecoder().decode(StructMain.self, from: data!)
```

```
struct StructMain: Decodable {
    let result: Bool //ok
    let message: String //ok
    let messageType: String //ok
    let action: String //ok
    let tablesArray: [Tables] //trouble
}
```

```
//This is my all tables but at some requests can't be all in tablesArray. i understand i must to use if condition or like that...

struct Tables: Decodable {
    let settingsTable: [SettingsTable]
    let userTable: [UserTable]
    let memberTable: [MemberTable]
    let personnelTable: [PersonnelTable]
    let notificationsTable: [NotificationsTable]
    let paymentsTable: [PaymentsTable]
    let debitsTable: [DebitsTable]
    let checksTable: [ChecksTable]
    let logsTable: [LogsTable]
    let qrsTable: [QrsTable]
}
```

```
//For settingsTable;

struct SettingsTable: Decodable {
    let id: String
    let available: String
    let forceToUpdate: String
    let currentVersion: String
    let versionMessage: String
}

//For others etc....
```

i tried all examples in stackoverflow but i can't find an example or question like my JSON struct.

How can i parse my variable json in swift. Can you help me?

Thank you...

Comment: In your `struct Tables` add a `?` to those tables that can be missing from your data. 
For example, your sample json data does not have `notificationsTable`. So use:
`var notificationsTable: [NotificationsTable]?`. You will need to consult the API 
docs to determine which are optional. Note, you have an extra `,` in your json data at `"memberStatusDescription": "Created by system",`

Comment: Use QuickType.io

Comment: Making the properties in Tables optional as mentioned above is the most straightforward solution and should work as long as the tables always comes in the same order in the json. Otherwise you need a custom decoder where you try to decode as every possible type until it works.

Comment: thank you, a question mark changed everything :)